# Who is God in the Old Testament? (Trinity)

Tags: old-testament, persons-of-the-trinity

I had always thought the Entity of the Trinity that appears in the Old Testament was God the Father. However, upon re-reading several passages, I am beginning to think it might be Jesus Christ.

The Referenced Verses, John 6:46 and John 14:6 - Which say 'Not that anyone has seen the father, except he who is from God (Jesus Christ)' and 'Nobody can come to the father except through me(Jesus Christ)' (ESV)

From these Statements from Christ, I am inclined to believe the 'LORD' in the old testament was actually Jesus Christ, and not the Father - as I've always assumed. If Nobody has ever come to the Father, or seen the Father except through Christ - Moses must not have been interacting with the Father, Right?

Please let me know what you think of this. Did the Old Testament ever make specific reference that God was God the Father?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about theophanies specifically? Which time(s) of Moses seeing God are you referring to?

Comment: Excellent question. (+1) Thought provoking. I look forward to further questions along the same lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Whoever sees Jesus sees God (John 14:9).

> John 1:18 (ESV)
> **No one has ever seen God; the only God**, who is at the Father's side, **he has made him known**.

No one has seen God. Jesus , who is God (by nature), is the One who reveals God (the Father) to us.

In the Old Testament, God said that no one can see him and live yet other accounts said that people did see him and they lived. The one whom they saw was the angel of the Lord, who was the pre incarnate Christ. This is not to say that Jesus was ontologically an angel. The word 'angel' (ανγγελος - *messenger*) refers to function.
Justin Martyr in the second century identified the angel of the Lord as the pre incarnate Christ.

> "Moreover, I consider it necessary to repeat to you the words which narrate how ***He who is both Angel and God and Lord, and who appeared as a man to Abraham, and who wrestled in human form with Jacob, was seen by him when he fled from his brother Esau***." (Dialogue with Trypho the Jew, Justin Martyr)

The Lord Jesus in the New Testament revealed was described as the following which consistently identifies him with the God whom ancient Israelites saw in the Old Testament:

(a) *Christ is the image of the invisible God.* (Col 1:15)

(b) *whoever sees Christ sees God* (John 14:9)

(b) *Christ himself is God by nature* (John 1:1, 1:18 cf. Col 2:9).

(c) *Those who has seen Christ actually lived* (John 6:40).

> John 6:40 7(ESV)
> For this is the will of my Father, that **everyone who looks on the Son** and believes in him should **have eternal life**, and I will raise him up on the last day.

**Conclusion**

Based on the New Testament and Ante-Nicene father, the Second Person of the Trinity is the Lord God *who appeared in the form of a man* to the Jewish patriarchs.

Comment: David says in Psalm 110 : The LORD said unto my Lord. He was aware of 'The LORD' through him he called 'my Lord'. _Out of the bush_ Elohim spoke to Moses and _in the bush_ was the angel of the LORD. And Jehovah _looked down_ from above. (+1). (Except I think it incorrect to use the actual name 'Jesus' until the incarnation, myself.)